# splitting a list dynamically with range and value to split

Tags: python, list, math, numpy

I want to split the value into number of spits provided. so for example if I have a `value = 165340`
and `split = 5` then the list should become `['0-33068', '33069-66137', '66138-99204', '99205-132272', '132273-165340']`...

so far I have just come up with something like this but this is not dynamic...
so thinking how can I build a list of strings like of numbers split with the difference `val/split`

```
for i in range(split):
    if i==0:
        lst.append('%s-%s' % (i, val/split))
    elif i==1:
        lst.append('%s-%s' % (val/split+i, val/split*2+1))
    elif i == 2:
        lst.append('%s-%s' % (val/split*i+2, val/split*3))
    elif i == 3:
        lst.append('%s-%s' % (val/split*i+1, val/split*4))
    elif i == 4:
        lst.append('%s-%s' % (val/split*i+1, val/split*5))
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Did you notice that, since you started counting at 0, you had 165341 numbers to divide by 5? Instead of trying to work around it like you did when `i == 1`, why not start at 1 (`range(1, value)`)?

Comment: I'm not really sure why OP's using the numbers he's using. Note that the difference in his ranges is `[33068, 33068, 33066, 33067, 33067]`

Comment: @san, what happens when you calculate  a value like 165347 and the split is 5?

Comment: well, the range in each string can be made same but the first number in the string should always be + 1 more than the last number in previous string in list, and the since max value is 165340 the last number of the last string in the list should not go more than the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### FINAL:

I made a bunch of attempts here, especially in using `remainder = value % numsplits`, then `int(i * remainder // numsplits)` to try and keep things close. Eventually, though, I had to give up and go back to floating point which seems to give the closest results. The usual floating point concerns apply.

```
def segment(value, numsplits):
    return ["{}-{}".format(
        int(round(1 + i * value/(numsplits*1.0),0)),
        int(round(1 + i * value/(numsplits*1.0) +
              value/(numsplits*1.0)-1, 0))) for
        i in range(numsplits)]

>>> segment(165340, 5)
['1-33068', '33069-66136', '66137-99204', '99205-132272', '132273-165340']
>>> segment(7, 4)
['1-2', '3-4', '4-5', '6-7']
```

I don't see a huge issue with this one. I did start at 1 instead of 0, but that's not necessary (change both the `int(round(1 + i * ...` to `int(round(i * ...` to change that). Old results follow.

```
value = 165340
numsplits = 5
result = ["{}-{}".format(i + value//numsplits*i, i + value//numsplits*i + value//numsplits) for i in range(numsplits)]
```

Probably worth tossing in a function

```
def segment(value,numsplits):
    return ["{}-{}".format(value*i//numsplits, 1 + value//numsplits*i + value//numsplits) for i in range(numsplits)]
```

The following will cut it off at your value

```
def segment(value, numsplits):
    return ["{}-{}".format(max(0,i + value*i//numsplits), min(value,i + value*i//numsplits + value//numsplits)) for i in range(numsplits)]
```

Comment: Since this properly labels a table, now you can use `np.histogram` to bin sort in data :-)

Comment: returns `165344` for the last value

Comment: @PadraicCunningham because the split isn't even. Editing to fix :)

Comment: Not quite - try `segment(7, 4)` :)

Comment: @AirThomas what would the correct output be for (7,4)?

Comment: Depending how you interpret the request, there are several potentially correct outputs - but `['0-1', '2-3', '5-6', '8-7']` is almost certainly not one of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56384/discussion-between-airthomas-and-adam-smith).

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question, it's important to know exactly how we should treat `0` - but it doesn't seem like you've asked yourself this question. The intervals in your example output are inconsistent; you're starting with `0` in the first interval and the first two intervals both have 33,069 elements (counting `0`) in them, but you're also ending your last interval at `165340`. **If `0` and `165340` are both counted in the number of elements, then `165340` is *not* divisible into five even intervals.**

Here are a few different solutions that might help you understand the problem.

### Even intervals, counting from zero

Let's start with the assumption that you really do want both `0` and the "top" value counted as elements and displayed in the result. In other words, the value 11 would actually indicate the following 12-element range:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

And be evenly split into the following non-negative intervals:

```
['0-3', '4-7', '8-11']
```

If we're only concerned with evenly-divisible cases, we can use a fairly short function (NOTE: These solutions are valid for Python 3.x, or for Python 2.x with `from __future__ import division`):

```
>>> def evenintervals(value, n):
...     binsize = (value + 1) // n
...     intervals = ((x * binsize, (x + 1) * binsize - 1) for x in range(n))
...     return ['{}-{}'.format(x, y) for x, y in intervals]
... 
>>> evenintervals(11, 3)
['0-3', '4-7', '8-11']
>>> evenintervals(17, 2)
['0-8', '9-17']
```

However, this function deals with `165340` (and any other not-evenly-divisible case) by dropping some numbers off the end:

```
>>> evenintervals(165340, 5)
['0-33067', '33068-66135', '66136-99203', '99204-132271', '132272-165339']
```

From a purely mathematical perspective, this just doesn't work. However, we *could* fudge it a bit if for some reason you want to *display* `0`, but not actually *count* it as an element of the first interval.

### Even intervals, counting from one

Here's a function that doesn't count `0` as an element of the list, but *does* give you the option of displaying it, if you're just that zany:

```
>>> def evenintervals1(value, n, show_zero=False):
...     binsize = value // n
...     intervals = [[x * binsize + 1, (x + 1) * binsize] for x in range(n)]
...     if show_zero:
...         intervals[0][0] = 0
...     return ['{}-{}'.format(x, y) for x, y in intervals]
... 
>>> evenintervals1(20, 4)
['1-5', '6-10', '11-15', '16-20']
>>> evenintervals1(20, 5, show_zero=True)
['0-5', '6-10', '11-15', '16-20']
```

This version of the function might be the closest thing to what you *asked* for in your question, even though it doesn't show the exact values you gave in your example output:

```
>>> evenintervals1(165340, 5, show_zero=True)
['0-33068', '33069-66136', '66137-99204', '99205-132272', '132273-165340']
```

But we still have problems with inputs that aren't evenly divisible. What if we wanted a more general solution?

### Uneven intervals

Let's think about how to deal with a wider range of inputs. We should be able to produce, from any positive integer `n`, anywhere from `1` to `n` non-overlapping ranges of positive integers. In other words, if our integer is `5`, we want to be able to produce a list with as many as five ranges. But how should we distribute "extra" elements, in order to make the ranges as even as possible?

We probably don't want to distribute them randomly. We could just lengthen or shorten the last range in the list, but that has the potential to be very lop-sided:

```
# 40 split 7 times, adding remainder to last item
['1-5', '6-10', '11-15', '16-20', '21-25', '26-30', '31-40']

# 40 split 7 times, subtracting excess from last item
['1-6', '7-12', '13-18', '19-24', '25-30', '31-36', '37-40']
```

In the former case the last element is 100% larger than the others and in the latter case it's 33% smaller. If you're splitting a very large value into a much smaller number of intervals, this may not be as much of a problem.

More likely, we want a function that produces the most even set of ranges possible. I'm going to do this by spreading the remainder of the division out among the first elements of the list, with a little help from `itertools`:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest  # izip_longest for Python 2.7
>>> def anyintervals(value, n):
...     binsize, extras = value // n, value % n
...     intervals = []
...     lower = 0
...     upper = 0
...     for newbinsize in map(sum, zip_longest([binsize] * n, [1] * extras, fillvalue=0)):
...         lower, upper = upper + 1, upper + newbinsize
...         intervals.append((lower, upper))
...     return ['{}-{}'.format(x, y) for x, y in intervals]
... 
>>> anyintervals(11, 3)
['1-4', '5-8', '9-11']
>>> anyintervals(17, 2)
['1-9', 10-17']
```

Finally, with the example inputs given in the OP:

```
>>> anyintervals(165340, 5)
['1-33068', '33069-66136', '66137-99204', '99205-132272', '132273-165340']
```

If it were really important to show the first interval starting at zero, we could apply the same logic here that was used in `evenintervals1` to modify the very first integer in `intervals` before returning, or write a similar function to this one that started counting at zero.

I did implement another version that distributes the "extras" among the last ranges rather than the first, and there are certainly many other implementations that you might be interested in fiddling around with, but those solutions are left as an exercise to the reader. ;)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility using numpy:

```
from numpy import arange
v = 165340
s = 5
splits = arange(s + 1) * (v / s)
lst = ['%d-%d' % (splits[idx], splits[idx+1]) for idx in range(s)]
print '\n'.join(lst)
```

output:

```
0-33068
33068-66136
66136-99204
99204-132272
132272-165340
```